# Ground symbol issue in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using TexLive2013 and the Circuitikz package.

I'm trying to draw the `ground` symbol but it appears as just a line and not the proper symbol.

The code I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{circuitikz} 
    \draw (0,0) to [ground] (0,-1); 
  \end{circuitikz} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But what I get is this:

[image]
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is absolutely normal: the symbol ground is a node shape, hence it mandatory to adopt the TikZ `\node` syntax.

Specifically, one should change

```
\draw (0,0) to [ground] (0,-1);
```

into

```
\draw (0,0) to (0,-1) node[ground]{};
```

or the equivalent

```
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1) node[ground]{};
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1) node[ground]{}; 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Note: the previous edit suggesting `\draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to (0,-1) ; ` option has been removed since it is very unlikely to place a `ground` in the middle of a wire within a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}` conflicts with the ground and causes this behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That cannot be the cause here though, as the OP doesn't load that library.

Comment: In my case, that was the reason. I load the library circuits.ee.IEC
Thanks for the hint, very helpfull for me. I have lost an hour to fix this.